# How to upload big size image file on imgur using httpwebrequest c#

Tags: c#, imgur

I have a question about upload big size file on imgur.

I found a source code for uploading images on imgur.com using api

It works for small size image file but it doesn't work for big size image file

I have tested with 488kb size image file.

The error returns 400 bad request server error.

Here is my source code and please give me an advice
Thank you

```
private string upload_img(string img_name)
   {
       string img_url = "";
       try
       {
           string api_url_image = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";
         //  string api_url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload";

           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(api_url_image);
           request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID <<My client ID Here>>");    //authorized id


           request.Method = "POST";


           FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
           byte[] image = new byte[file.Length];
           file.Read(image, 0, (int)file.Length);
           ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
           string postData = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
           byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes(postData);

           request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
           request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

           Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream();
           writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

           HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
           response.GetResponseStream();

           if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
           {

               Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
               string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();

               img_url = responseStr.Remove(0, responseStr.IndexOf("link") + 7);
               img_url = img_url.Substring(0, img_url.IndexOf("success") - 4);
               img_url = img_url.Replace("\\","");
               responseStream.Close();
           }
           response.Close();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }

       return img_url;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

When I downlaod the image file and save it.
I limited the file size like below
It was my mistake :)

private string download_img(string url)
        {

```
        string imageUrl = @url;
        string img_name = imageUrl.Replace("http://i.imgur.com/", "");
        string saveLocation = @"C:\folder_name\" + img_name;

        byte[] imageBytes;
        HttpWebRequest imageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
        WebResponse imageResponse = imageRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream();

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(responseStream))
        {
            imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(500000);
            br.Close();
        }
        responseStream.Close();
        imageResponse.Close();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        try
        {
            bw.Write(imageBytes);
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
            bw.Close();
        }

        return img_name;

    }
    private string download_img2(string url)
    {

        string imageUrl = @url;
        string img_name = imageUrl.Replace("http://i.imgur.com/", "");
        string saveLocation = @"C:\ssulf\" + img_name;

        byte[] imageBytes;
        HttpWebRequest imageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
        WebResponse imageResponse = imageRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream();

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(responseStream))
        {
            // imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(500000);
            imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(1000000);
            br.Close();
        }
        responseStream.Close();
        imageResponse.Close();



        FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        try
        {
            bw.Write(imageBytes);
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
            bw.Close();
        }

        return img_name;

    }
```